# Could not render "app.html" for X.Web.LayoutView, please define a matching clause for render/2

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

After renaming my app from Livestory to Citybuilder, I can't launch it.

`mix phx.server` returns:

```
Could not render "app.html" for Citybuilder.Web.LayoutView, please define a matching clause for render/2 or define a template at "lib/Citybuilder/web/templates/layout". No templates were compiled for this module.
```

I've checked, and app.html.eex is in the file structure, where it should be.

The fault may lay in the file structure or cases of the words.

Comment: What do you mean by "renaming my app from Livestory to Citybuilder"? Have you renamed all of the modules? Perhaps removing whole `_build` directory and recompiling would help? Otherwise, you need check your `lib/Citybuilder/web/views` for `*View` modules, check `lib/Citybuilder/web/web.ex` to update all the occurrences of `Livestory` to `Citybuilder` and finally, very similar thing in `lib/Citybuilder/web/endpoint.ex`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go through that list. Yes, I renamed all the modules. I did a find and replace for every instance of Livestory in the code, and swapped it with Citybuilder. As expected, it caused problems.

Comment: I have a feeling you need to check your `lib/Citybuilder/web/web.ex` around line 30, there should be something like `use Phoenix.View, root: "lib/Livestory/web/templates"`, but you want to update this as well. I've just gone through very similar process and that was an issue! Let me know if that worked so I can post it as final answer!

Comment: I just checked, and Livestory was successfully changed to Citybuilder in the batch rename: line 33: "lib/Citybuilder/web/templates"... I need to look deeply at the file structure and upper/lower cases now.

Comment: Where are you calling render? Can you test it with direct call of render? `Phoenix.View.render(Your.View, "your_template.html, assigns)`

Comment: I'll have to try that in a couple of days, something came up... a simple test like that is good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I recloned the app.

- Did a case sensitive replace of livestory to citybuilder
- Another case sensitive replace of Livestory to Citybuilder

I then changed

lib/livestory/web/templates/layout

to

lib/citybuilder/web/templates/layout

and the app ran OK.